# Sketching image of paths in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry

In each of the following describe the image of $f \circ \gamma$ for all $t$ in the indicated range. Given
$$\gamma (t) = it : -1 \le t \le 1 $$
and $$ f(z) = \frac{z + 1}{z - 1}$$

It's clear to me that $f(\gamma (t)) = \frac{(1-t^2) + (2t)i}{-t^2 - 1}$ but the solutions say that we let $Re(z) = x, Im(z) = y$ and that it's clear then that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

I'm struggling to see a method whereby it's clear to see $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ other than through lucky guesses. Does anyone know how I can begin to find where the solutions got this equality from?

Comment: That's very nice of you to tell us that $\gamma(t)$ is $i(t)$, but what is $i(t)$ ?

Comment: I think he just means $i\cdot t$, that is, the imaginary unit multiplied by $t$.

Comment: oh that explains it, sorry.

Comment: Sorry. I've changed it as it was confusing.